# Как запихнуть результат работы цикла в строку?

Tags: java

```
for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++)
{
     System.out.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : "");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

мда, ну и вопросы пошли ... А подумать ? :) Как жеж так ?

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++)
{
    sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
}
String ret = sb.toString();
System.out.print(ret);
```

как то так...

Comment: StringBuiler() =)

Comment: @Gorets, а разница ? :)

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!

Comment: shurik, это как раз что мне надо, спасибо!!!

Comment: @shurik Разница только в скорости: StringBuilder не threadsafe, поэтому он быстрее StringBuffer